# How to share real time processed data from C# to python

Tags: c#, python, share, real-time-data

I want to pass some data processed in C# in real time to another python application for further realtime processing. I have trying to log those data into CSV file and let the python to read it simultaneously, however it seems that windows lock the CSV file and I can not read the file at the same time when C# is logging into it.

Does anyone know how to share real time data from C# to python?

Comment: You may use our libraries, as mentioned in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34788064/1952991

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a pipe: print out the stuff, and have the python program read it.

Files are more flexible. You can use them, you just have to change how you create them. When you create your [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx), make sure to Specify [FileShare.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx).